# Encountered problems here like 'runtime error 3705' operation is not allowed when the object is open

Tags: sql-server, vb6

This is all the code of my program:

```
Option Explicit
Dim aConnection As New ADODB.Connection

 Private Sub cmdNew_Click()
 Dim sql As String

 sql = "INSERT INTO Table_Employee(ID, Fullname, Address, Birthdate, Age, Date_Registered, 
 Position, Status) values("
 sql = sql & "'" & txtID.Text & "',"
 sql = sql & "'" & txtName.Text & "',"
 sql = sql & "'" & txtAddress.Text & "',"
 sql = sql & "'" & cboBirthdate.Value & "',"
 sql = sql & "'" & txtAge.Text & "',"
 sql = sql & "'" & cboRegistered.Value & "',"
 sql = sql & "'" & txtPosition.Text & "',"
 sql = sql & "'" & cmbStatus.Text & "')"

aConnection.Open sql
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
aConnection.Open _
    "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & _
    "Data Source=DESKTOP-8KUB2UC;" & _
    "Initial Catalog=EmployeeMasterfile;" & _
    "Trusted_Connection=YES;"
    
    Adodc1.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
aConnection.Close
End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJAce.png)

I'm currently on a training and running a program that can Add, edit, update, search and delete. Anyone can help me to fix my problem or can help me to do my project. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Since you're on a training course, I'm reluctant to give you a full answer but think what the error message on that line is telling you. Hint: You've already opened the connection in Form_Load.  Look up the Execute command!

Comment: Are you taking a course in retro computing?

Answer (score 0):

in fact, since your db connection is open already you should use the following when inserting a new data
aConnection.Execute sql